# css media queries ignored

Tags: css, media-queries

I want my page look nice with iphone4 and iphone 5. I wrote some media queries, but it seems they are ignored:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

#gpsMain{
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    left:20%;
}

}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {

#gpsMain{
    position:absolute;
    top:11px;
    left:20%;
}

}
```

Why the styles are not applied? Is this the correct way to get resolutions of the two iphone?

(The queries are the last thing I wrote on css document)

Comment: Common troubleshooting.. do you have a [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) set..?

Comment: I was just about to ask that ^^

Comment: yes:<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 2):

Double check to see if you have a viewport set.  Not sure if it matters but I always see media queries formatted like so:

```
@-ms-viewport {
    width: device-width;
}

@viewport {
    width: device-width;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .list-view .site-content .post-thumbnail { background: none; width: auto; z-index: 2; }
}
```

This is from the 2014 wordpress theme.  http://www.responsinator.com/ is a good place to double check how things are looking.

Comment: As I commented above, I have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> in my page

Answer (score 0):

Try change into this:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

#gpsMain{
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    left:20%;
}

}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {

#gpsMain{
    position:absolute;
    top:11px;
    left:20%;
}

}
```